# How do I setup an Airflow of 2 servers?

Tags: airflow

Trying to split out Airflow processes onto 2 servers. Server A, which has been already running in standalone mode with everything on it, has the DAGs and I'd like to set it as the worker in the new setup with an additional server.

Server B is the new server which would host the metadata database on MySQL.

Can I have Server A run LocalExecutor, or would I have to use CeleryExecutor? Would `airflow scheduler` has to run on the server that has the DAGs right? Or does it have to run on every server in a cluster? Confused as to what dependencies there are between the processes

Answer (score 10):

[This article](http://site.clairvoyantsoft.com/setting-apache-airflow-cluster/) does an excellent job demonstrating how to cluster Airflow onto multiple servers.

**Multi-Node (Cluster) Airflow Setup**

A more formal setup for Apache Airflow is to distribute the daemons across multiple machines as a cluster.

[image]

**Benefits**

*Higher Availability*

If one of the worker nodes were to go down or be purposely taken offline, the cluster would still be operational and tasks would still be executed.

*Distributed Processing*

If you have a workflow with several memory intensive tasks, then the tasks will be better distributed to allow for higher utilizaiton of data across the cluster and provide faster execution of the tasks.

**Scaling Workers**

*Horizontally*

You can scale the cluster horizontally and distribute the processing by adding more executor nodes to the cluster and allowing those new nodes to take load off the existing nodes. Since workers don’t need to register with any central authority to start processing tasks, the machine can be turned on and off without any downtime to the cluster.

*Vertically*

You can scale the cluster vertically by increasing the number of celeryd daemons running on each node. This can be done by increasing the value in the ‘celeryd_concurrency’ config in the {AIRFLOW_HOME}/airflow.cfg file.

**Example:**

```
celeryd_concurrency = 30
```

You may need to increase the size of the instances in order to support a larger number of celeryd processes. This will depend on the memory and cpu intensity of the tasks you’re running on the cluster.

**Scaling Master Nodes**

You can also add more Master Nodes to your cluster to scale out the services that are running on the Master Nodes. This will mainly allow you to scale out the Web Server Daemon incase there are too many HTTP requests coming for one machine to handle or if you want to provide Higher Availability for that service.

One thing to note is that there can only be one Scheduler instance running at a time. If you have multiple Schedulers running, there is a possibility that multiple instances of a single task will be scheduled. This could cause some major problems with your Workflow and cause duplicate data to show up in the final table if you were running some sort of ETL process.

If you would like, the Scheduler daemon may also be setup to run on its own dedicated Master Node.

[image]

**Apache Airflow Cluster Setup Steps**

*Pre-Requisites*

- The following nodes are available with the given host names:

  - master1 - Will have the role(s): Web Server, Scheduler
  - master2 - Will have the role(s): Web Server
  - worker1 - Will have the role(s): Worker
  - worker2 - Will have the role(s): Worker
- A Queuing Service is Running. (RabbitMQ, AWS SQS, etc)

  - You can install RabbitMQ by following these instructions: Installing RabbitMQ
  - If you’re using RabbitMQ, it is recommended that it is also setup to be a cluster for High Availability. Setup a Load Balancer to proxy requests to the RabbitMQ instances.

[image]

[image]

**Additional Documentation**

- Documentation: https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/
- Install Documentation: https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/installation.html
- GitHub Repo: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow

Comment: The question seems a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), so this is not a good answer for it, but for me and 90% of the pageviews, **this is the best answer**!

Answer (score 4):

All airflow processes need to have the same contents in their `airflow_home` folder. This includes configuration and dags. If you only want server B to run your MySQL database, you do not need to worry about any airflow specifics. Simply install the database on server B and change your airflow.cfg's `sql_alchemy_conn` parameter to point to your database on Server B and run airflow initdb from Server A.

If you also want to run airflow processes on server B, you would have to look into scaling using the [CeleryExecutor](https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/configuration.html#scaling-out-with-celery).

Comment: This is the **best answer** when  we suppose that the question is a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).